# Failed asserting that 1 matches expected 0 in laravel testing

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5.4

I'm getting error like below

`Found unexpected records in database table [customers] that matched attributes [{"id":89}].
Failed asserting that 1 matches expected 0.`

CustomerTest.php:

```
public function testDestroyCustomer()
 {
        // $this->assertTrue(true);
        $post = factory(Customer::class,1)->create();
        $this->delete(route('customer.destroy', $post->id));
        $this->assertResponseStatus(500);
        $this->dontSeeInDatabase('customers', ['id' => $post->id]);
 }
```

Routes.php

```
Route::resource('customer', 'CustomerController', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'customer'
    ]
]);
```

Destroy function in CustomerController :

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $delete = Customer::where('id',$id)->delete();
    }
```

How do i resolve the error ? any suggestions please .

Comment: the where query might be returning a collection, try chaining first() after the where clause, or use find() instead.

Comment: @WreighChristianSantos : i have tried both still the error persists . any idea ?

Comment: should the Route names be declared for index only? I'm not familiar about that since I do not use that kind of format for names. Anyways I think if the route destroy can't be found, it should throw 404 right?

Comment: I think your route call for delete should be, route('customer.destroy', ['id' => $post->id]);

Comment: Okay lemme check by changing  my routes

Answer (score 0):

I think your route call for delete should be,

Change:

```php
route('customer.destroy', $post->id);
```

to

```php
route('customer.destroy', ['id' => $post->id]);
```

Comment: i think the error didn't come out because you've asserted error 500 to happen.

Comment: There is no error now . But record is inserted in database . delete is not happening . I have a doubt will it delete the record or will it just check the destroy function is correct or not ?

Comment: i don't know much about unit testing in Laravel but you can call the destroy route like what's been said here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/howto-test-delete-method-in-laravel-51